# using regexp_substr to capture all characters between two words (including the front and end of the string

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

So I have been mostly using regexp_like and not regexp_substr- 
but in the strings below

```
'abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 imp 2/8/15 xxx cc2' 
'3/10/18 bla bla imp-3/9/17 xfe 334 3/4/13'

I want to capture 
imp 2/8/15 xxx cc2
imp-3/9/17 xfe
```

In regexp_like, it would simply be regexp_like('abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 imp 2/8/15 xxx cc2','(imp).{0,20}(cc2|xfe)') but it doesn't work the same way with regexp_substr

I have tried using this code below w/o success.

```
with test (id, col) as
      (select 1, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah IMP 3/7/16'                     from dual union all
      select 2, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 imp 2/8/15 xxx cc2'      from dual union all
      select 3, 'xxx 3/5/18 ccdd 234 imp happened on 5/8/19 some 23f' from dual union all
      select 4, '3/10/18 bla bla imp-3/9/17 xfe 334 3/4/13 x'         from dual
      )
   select id,
      regexp_substr('(imp).*(xxx|xfe)',1) result
  from test;
```

Need to account for capitalization!

Suggestions appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `col` at all in your query.

Try this:

```
with test (id, col) as
      (select 1, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah IMP 3/7/16'                     from dual union all
      select 2, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 imp 2/8/15 xxx cc2'      from dual union all
      select 3, 'xxx 3/5/18 ccdd 234 imp happened on 5/8/19 some 23f' from dual union all
      select 4, '3/10/18 bla bla imp-3/9/17 xfe 334 3/4/13 x'         from dual
      )
   select id,
      regexp_substr(col, '(imp).*(xxx|xfe)',1, 1) result -- use occurance as 1, last parameter
  from test;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=019dedb51a5bcd349027f3541101e7a7)

Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, the col might help!  Def not enough coffee yet this morning. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: question -the strings I have are al ot longer and can repeat-how can I limit to the first and get rid of rest of string?

Comment: This will return first occurance when occurance parameter is 1. Updated in answer as well as in the db fiddle

Comment: I ma still getting really strings after, going to try and post real examples- need to be careful as this is real PHI  information.

Comment: Ok I changed is so that  it is  regexp_substr(col, '(imp){0,20}(xxx|xfe)',1, 1) result and that better but what if I wanted to finish off the word so let's say importantly, or important if I would were to switch it-  regexp_substr(col, '(xxx){0,20}(imp)',1, 1)